# ID CS6: Can I set an exact height for a cell style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, cell

I am working in a table. I am creating cell styles for various kinds of cells.

I want to create what is essentially a spacer cell (unless there's some way to create padding-above like in CSS :) ) which always has an exact height of p6. I can do this manually, but I can't find anywhere to do it in a style sheet. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Table Panel (or control bar with a table highlighted) you can set the cell height to "Exactly" and insert the value you want.

[image: table panel]

But... you're right.. you can't save this particular aspect to a cell or table style.

To use a style you might try this....

- Create a paragraph style which sets the type size to match your desired cell height. For example, 6pt type for a 6pt tall cell.
  [image: paragraph style]
- Create a new Cell Style and set it to use the paragraph style you just created.
  [image: style]
- Set the Cell Insets in the Cell Style Options to zero. 
  [image: cellinsets]

That should allow you to select a row (or cell) and apply the cell style to get a spacer which matches the height of your predefined Paragraph Style.

**Another option** would be to simply create a **Cell Style with a larger Top Inset** to move the cell items down. Basically a taller cell style to create the appearance of a spacer, without actually having a spacer row. This tends to fail if you want to alternate fills or strokes though.

[image: inset]

Comment: Excellent, that worked! Great combination of tools.